# Python argparse without character -

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

Using Python and argparse library I can catch options for scripts

```
parser.add_argument('-s','--status', action='store_true')

python script.py -s
```

How could it be done to pass options without leading character `-` ?

```
python script.py status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set [`nargs='?'`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs) for the argument:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('status', nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.status
```

Here's what on the command-line:

```
$ python test.py --help
usage: test.py [-h] [status]

positional arguments:
  status

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

$ python test.py my_status
my_status
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an argument, not an option. You can read about how to do that in the [argparse docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html). If you look at the [first example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#example), "N" is an argument.